# Try / Except error handling Selenium / Python

Tags: python, selenium, loops, error-handling

Creating a script that will pull user information from AD and pass that information into a automation program that generates user accounts for a webpage. I have been able to get through the entire webpage but I am running into an issue with the script handling a username error. Basically if the username is already taken I want it to add a 1 to the end of the user name. If the user name with a one is taken I want it to backspace and add a 2 etc until the error no longer pops up. Once that happens I want to skip the rest of the loop and move on through the rest of the code.

I am currently using a try except to catch the error and it works but will only add 1 to the username before moving on even if the condition is not met. I need it to keep going until that user account has been created.

Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Selenium Python Script

```
count = 0 
# #Submit Button 
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Add User']"))).click()

try:
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class= "error-section"]//p[contains(.,"Sorry, something unexpected happened. Please try again.")]')))
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="data"]/div[1]/button'))).click()
   UserName.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
   count = count + 1
   UserName.send_keys(count)
   UserName.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
   UserName.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c')   
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Add User']"))).click()

except TimeoutException as ex:
         print("no error")
```

Comment: That is correct. Ideally the script wouldn't need to even wait for the TimeoutException but seems to be the only way for it to recognize the error on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a fixed value of "1" to the name found as already existing you can add some random string, lets say it will start with underscore for indication and after the underscore a random string of 4-6 signs. This will insure you will not need to do this looping.

Comment: Unfortunately the company policy is to just add a number and one digit up if needed. I can get it to cycle through the numbers with a while loop no problem it is just if the profile doesn’t need a number it skips the rest of the code and throws an error or I can use the try except and it will just go to 1 but it does finnish the code if the username doesn’t need a number.